# Named Templates in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I am new in EmberJS and flowing on [www.codeschool.com](https://www.codeschool.com/) the **Warming Up With Ember.js**  ...

I am stuck at level *1.4 Named Template*, They ask me to: ***Move the content unique to our homepage into a new template and give it a template name that will be shown on the homepage of our site.***
for  this code,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href='http://courseware.codeschool.com/ember/' />
  <link href='bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='application.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src='jquery.js'></script>
  <script src='handlebars.js'></script>
  <script src='ember.js'></script>
  <script src='ember-data.js'></script>
  <script src='app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>
    <div class='navbar navbar-default'>
      <div class='container'>
        <a href='#' class='navbar-brand'><img src='images/logo.png' alt='logo' height='34' width='224' /></a>
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
          <li href='#' class='active'>Home</li>
          <li href='#/about'>About</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
      <h1>Welcome to The Flint &amp; Flame!</h1>
    </div>
    <footer class='container'>
      <hr />
      <p class='pull-left'>&copy; 2013 The Flint &amp; Flame</p>
      <p class='pull-right'><a href='#/credits'>Credits</a></p>
    </footer>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I did it but it still don't work after trying this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href='http://courseware.codeschool.com/ember/' />
  <link href='bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='application.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src='jquery.js'></script>
  <script src='handlebars.js'></script>
  <script src='ember.js'></script>
  <script src='ember-data.js'></script>
  <script src='app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>
    <div class='navbar navbar-default'>
      <div class='container'>
        <a href='#' class='navbar-brand'><img src='images/logo.png' alt='logo' height='34' width='224' /></a>
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
          <li href='#' class='active'>Home</li>
          <li href='#/about'>About</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
  <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='index'>
     <h1>Welcome to The Flint &amp; Flame!</h1>
    </script>
    </div>
    <footer class='container'>
      <hr />
      <p class='pull-left'>&copy; 2013 The Flint &amp; Flame</p>
      <p class='pull-right'><a href='#/credits'>Credits</a></p>
    </footer>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add an [outlet](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/the-application-template/) to your application template and you nested your index template inside your application template, which is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href='http://courseware.codeschool.com/ember/'/>
    <link href='bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <link href='application.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <script src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script src='handlebars.js'></script>
    <script src='ember.js'></script>
    <script src='ember-data.js'></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>
    <div class='navbar navbar-default'>
        <div class='container'>
            <a href='#' class='navbar-brand'><img src='images/logo.png' alt='logo' height='34' width='224'/></a>
            <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                <li href='#' class='active'>Home</li>
                <li href='#/about'>About</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='index'>
    <div class='container'>
        <h1>Welcome to The Flint &amp; Flame!</h1>
    </div>
    <footer class='container'>
        <hr/>
        <p class='pull-left'>&copy; 2013 The Flint &amp; Flame</p>

        <p class='pull-right'><a href='#/credits'>Credits</a></p>
    </footer>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```